# import url from excel into python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have this code but I need to import all the rows in a loop
I have an excel file with url links in one column, and I need to read those links to perform NLP on them. How can I use a loop to read those links? Here's my attempt so far:

```
import requests
link = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/3662/0000950170-98-000413.txt'
f = requests.get(link)
print(f.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have understood your question correctly you want to read an excel-file with some urls and perform an operation with every single url. In this case I would read the file with pandas. Assuming your file is named file.xlsx and has a column named url that contains all the urls, you could do the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel ('file.xlsx')

for url in df['url']:
    print(url) #or do some useful stuff with it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as req

#assuming column A has url links
mydata = pd.read_excel('/your_file.xlsx',usecols="A",header=None)
for index, row in mydata.iterrows():
    print(req.get(row))
```